# invoking a default method from a static context in Java

Tags: java

Why can't a default method in Java be invoked from a subclass's static method as in the following example (what is the logic behind this rule):

```
public class Child extends Parent
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
   System.out.println(dft_method(6));
}
}

class Parent
{
int dft_method(int a) { return a + 1; }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have the `Child` class declared twice, once extending `Parent`, once not? What you may be running into is that a static method (`main`) cannot access non-static methods (like `dft_method`) in the class because there is no instance of the object yet.

Comment: What is a "default" method and how does the compiler distinguish it from a "non-default" method? If you want to run a method in a static context without an instance, make it static.

Comment: My apologies stvcisco, there was a typo in my code. The second class was supposed to be the Parent.

Comment: That's not a default method. Default methods in Java 8 can only be declared on interfaces, and they have to use the keyword `default` in their declaration. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 0):

This works if you declare dft_method() as static. Right now, it can only be invoked from a Parent object, like:

```
new Parent().dft_method(6);
```

or:

```
new Child().dft_method(6);
```